# How to send a value which does not have a form field, along with the rest of the form fields to a table as a new record ms-access 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table called table1 with 4 fields: Age, name, birthdate, and haircolour. On the data entry form for that table, I only have 3 of the fields present with the age field being left out. These are all example fields. From the birthdate, I can calculate the age of the person in the background, but since the age field is not a part of the form, it doesn't automatically send the age data with the rest of the fields as a new record to table1.

How can I not include the age field in the form but still have it as input data to the new record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: think very hard if you really have a good reason to store a value in the table that can easily be calculated.

[Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

If there is a good reason: even if the `age` control **is** on the form, it cannot be calculated and bound to a table field with its `ControlSource` at the same time.

So: put the control on the form, bound to the table field, but set it to `Visible = False`.

Then in `AfterUpdate` of `Birthdate`, do the calculation and set the invisible control value so it will be saved with the record.

While debugging, it helps to have the control visible.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the age in a query and base your form on that query.

Comment: What do you mean by "base your form on that query"? Can you give specifics?

Comment: Just as I said. You create a query, calculate the age within that query and save the query. Next, you use that query as the record source for your form rather than a table. Quite common practice ;)

Comment: Just read Andre's reply. Indeed you shouldn't store calculated values in a table. If you persist you to do, remind that people tend to age, meaning your ages would be out of date tomorrow ;) You can simply continue using your current form and base it on a table. If you'd want to calculate someone's age, you'd need a separate query though (and/or VBA).